# how to make profile for each user

Tags: django

I have an app that if a user signs up, the app will automatically make a profile page for it, the sign up and login part works correctly but it doesn't make a profile page, I have to do it in the admin page. How should I solve this problem?

this is my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

this is my views.py

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request, f'Your Acount Has Been Created You Are Now Be Able to Login')
        return redirect('login')
else:
    form = UserRegisterForm()
return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST ,request.FILES , instance=request.user.profile)
    if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
        u_form.save()
        p_form.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Your Acount Has Been Updated')
        return redirect('profile')
else:
    u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

context = {
    'u_form':u_form,
    'p_form':p_form
}
return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

this is my forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2'] 


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email'] 


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

this is my signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created , **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

and this is my apps.py:

```
class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see that would cause this is that the signals aren't registering properly, make sure the config is referenced in the app's **init**.py file:

```
# my_app.__init__.py
default_app_config = 'my_app.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

Alternatively, move the signals to the models.py file and see if they fire when the User is created. As a last resort, try creating the profile in the view when the User form is saved.